# Update "Angular2 Mvc5 sample application" to latest version of Angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use ASP.NET MVC5 with Angular2 to make an application. For this I am using a ready made template available in Visual Studio Named ["Angular2 Mvc5 sample application"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Payns75.Angular2Mvc5sampleapplication). The package.json coming with the template tells that it is using rc-1 and related dependencies of Angular 2 and Typescript. Since the latest version of Angular 2 now is 2.4.0, I want to use the latest version of angular2 in my project. How can I do this? I tried updating the package.json file and change versions to the latest one

```
    {
      "name": "aspnet",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "typings install",
        "typings": "typings"
      },
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "typings": "0.8.1" 
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",

        "systemjs": "0.19.27",
        "core-js": "^2.4.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

        "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.9"
      }
    }
```

I took a reference from angular cli project to update the package, and after updating my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "aspnet",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typings": "~2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.9"
  }
}
```

After updating package.json > I restored packages but I am getting a lot of errors after building my project

These pics can help you know about errors [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you show errors?

Comment: Go to Visual Studio, help, about ... what version of TypeScript are you using? I suspect it's out-of-date.

Comment: @pixelbits its 1.8.36.0

Comment: Do you have the `node_modules` included in your project? It should be excluded.

Comment: @pixelbits yes its excluded. But why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade your Angular to latest version, pick and update your desired packages from this [package.json](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json) to your `package.json`. And to fix the errors you need to update the version of `nodejs` and `npm`. Once you have updated nodejs and npm installed, you must also add `nodejs` path in Visual Studio to use the latest version of nodejs and npm. To add path in VS, go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools. For this you can follow this [guide](http://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-2015-update-nodejs-andor-npm-latest-version/).

Comment: That's good, you can ask any time if you face any difficulty developing with Angular2.